# how can i migrate a flutter project to androidx:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'. > Android dependency 'androidx.versionedparcelable

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, package, androidx

i added a geolocator package in my flutter project and whenever i run i get errors about androidx compatibility and 
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
>   i added this in android/gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have try changing the build version but it's not working. I also try some solutions proposed by github pasting

i added this under the buidscript in android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }

            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all what i [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYWvz.png)did mas useless

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find out an answer after sometimes. I just needed to update flutter
and the followinng in the android/build.gradle under buildscript

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
                    !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add the following in the android/gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```